# Corollary 2.24 from Tao-Vu on asymmetric sum set inequalities

Tags: additive-combinatorics

I am trying to solve exercise 2.4.3 from Tao-Vu book

> Prove Corollary 2.24. What value of the implicit constant in the $O()$
> notation do you get?
>
> **Corollary 2.24 (Asymmetric sum set inequalities,
> preliminary version)** Let $A,B$ be additive sets with common ambient
> group $Z$. Then we have estimates $$d(n_1A-n_2A+n_3B-n_4B,
>  n_5A-n_6A+n_7B-n_8B)=O((n_1+\dots+n_8)d(A,B))$$ for any $n_1,\dots,
>  n_8\in \mathbb{N}$.

*An attemp of proof:* By definition of Ruzsa distance we have $$d(n_1A-n_2A+n_3B-n_4B,
 n_5A-n_6A+n_7B-n_8B)=$$ $$=\log \dfrac{|(n_1+n_6)A-(n_2+n_5)A+(n_3+n_8)B-(n_4+n_7)B|}{|n_1A-n_2A+n_3B-n_4B|^{1/2}|n_5A-n_6A+n_7B-n_8B|^{1/2}}\leq$$ $$\leq\log \dfrac{|(n_1+n_6)A-(n_2+n_5)A||(n_3+n_8)B-(n_4+n_7)B|}{|n_1A-n_2A+n_3B-n_4B|^{1/2}|n_5A-n_6A+n_7B-n_8B|^{1/2}}. \quad \quad(*)$$ Now we can use inequality $(2.17)$ on page 73 which says that $|mA-nA|\leq \delta[A]^{5(n+m-1)}|A|$ for all $m,n\geq 1$. Hence $$(*)\leq \log \dfrac{\delta[A]^{5(n_1+n_2+n_5+n_6-1)}\delta[B]^{5(n_3+n_4+n_7+n_8-1)}|A||B|}{|n_1A-n_2A+n_3B-n_4B|^{1/2}|n_5A-n_6A+n_7B-n_8B|^{1/2}}=$$ $$=5(n_1+n_2+n_5+n_6-1)d(A,A)+5(n_3+n_4+n_7+n_8-1)d(B,B)+$$ $$+\log \dfrac{|A||B|}{|n_1A-n_2A+n_3B-n_4B|^{1/2}|n_5A-n_6A+n_7B-n_8B|^{1/2}}.$$ Ruzsa's triangle inequality tell us that $d(A,A), d(B,B)\leq 2 d(A,B).$ Hence $$(*)\leq 10(n_1+\dots+n_8)d(A,B)+\log \dfrac{|A||B|}{|n_1A-n_2A+n_3B-n_4B|^{1/2}|n_5A-n_6A+n_7B-n_8B|^{1/2}}.$$ But the second term above can be estimated above roughly by $\log \sqrt{|A||B|}$.

I was trying to solve this probem all day but stucked. Would be grateful for any hints!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an answer but this is what I've gotten so far.

By definition of Ruzsa distance we have: $$d(n_1A-n_2A+n_3B-n_4B,
 n_5A-n_6A+n_7B-n_8B)=$$ $$=\log \dfrac{|(n_1+n_6)A-(n_2+n_5)A+(n_3+n_8)B-(n_4+n_7)B|}{|n_1A-n_2A+n_3B-n_4B|^{1/2}|n_5A-n_6A+n_7B-n_8B|^{1/2}}\leq$$ $$\leq \log \dfrac{|\alpha A-\alpha A+\alpha B-\alpha B|}{|n_1A-n_2A+n_3B-n_4B|^{1/2}|n_5A-n_6A+n_7B-n_8B|^{1/2}}, \quad \quad (*)$$ where $\alpha=\sum \limits_{k=1}^8n_k.$ Hence $$(*)\leq\log \dfrac{|\alpha(A-B)-\alpha(A-B)|}{|A|^{1/2}|B|^{1/2}}.$$ Also we know that $|\alpha(A-B)-\alpha(A-B)|\leq \delta[A-B]^{10\alpha}|A-B|.$ So we obtain that $$\leq \log \dfrac{\delta[A-B]^{10\alpha}|A-B|}{|A|^{1/2}|B|^{1/2}}=10\alpha \cdot d(A-B,A-B)+d(A,B).$$
That means that we need to obtain some bound on $d(A-B,A-B)$ in terms of $d(A,B)$.

**EDIT (this edit has been added after Thomas Blooms's hint:**

Dear, Prof. Bloom! I tried to follow your hint(of course, if I understand it correctly) and this is what I obtained so far: so our goal is to obtain some upper bound for $d(A-B,A-B)$ in terms of $d(A,B)$. Assume that $|A|\geq |B|$, then by Ruzsa's covering lemma we have that $B\subseteq A-A+X$ for some additive set $X$ suh that $|X|\leq \frac{|A-B|}{|A|}$.

Hence $A-A+B-B\subseteq 3A-3A+X-X$ and $$d(A-B,A-B)=\log \dfrac{|A-A+B-B|}{|A-B|}\leq \log\dfrac{|3A-3A||X|^2}{|A-B|}\leq \log \dfrac{\delta[A]^{5(3+3-1)}|A||A-B|^2}{|A|^2|A-B|}=$$ $$=\log \dfrac{\delta[A]^{25}|A-B|}{|A|}=25d(A,A)+\log \dfrac{|A-B|}{|A|}\leq 25d(A,A)+\log \dfrac{|A-B|}{|A|^{1/2}|B|^{1/2}}=25d(A,A)+d(A,B)\leq $$ $$\leq51d(A,B).$$

If $|A|\leq |B|$, then we need to cover $A$ by at most $\frac{|A-B|}{|B|}$ translates of $B-B$. The same reasoning shows us that $d(A-B,A-B)\leq 51 d(A,B)$. I guess this constant can be improved but that was not my final goal.  Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: Try using Ruzsa's covering lemma to cover $B$ by $\leq \lvert A+B\rvert/\lvert A\rvert$ many translates of $A-A$. This lets you turn the problem the bounding $\lvert 2A-2B\rvert$ into bounding $\lvert 3A-3A\rvert$, for example, which is handled by the discussion following Corollary 2.22 in Tao-Vu.

Comment: @ThomasBloom, please see my edit.

Comment: Yes, that looks right.

Comment: @ThomasBloom, thank you so much! Appreciate your help!

Comment: @ThomasBloom, dear Professor Bloom! Can you take a look at this question please if you have some spare time? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4396238/problem-2-4-8-rom-tao-vu-book