# Problem 2.4.8 rom Tao-Vu book

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, additive-combinatorics

> For each $j=1,2,3,$ let $G_j$ be a $K_j$-approximate group in an
> ambient group $Z$. Using the Ruzsa triangle inequality, show that
> $$|G_1+G_2+G_3|\leq K_2\dfrac{|G_1+G_2||G_2+G_3|}{|G_2|}.$$ Conclude
> that $$d(G_1+G_2, G_1+G_2+G_3)\leq d(G_2, G_2+G_3)+\log K_1K_2.$$
> Similarly for permutations. Conclude from this and the preceding
> exercise that $$d(G_1,G_2)\leq d(G_1+G_3, G_2+G_3)+2\log K_1K_2K_3.$$

This is a problem 2.4.8 from Tao-Vu book and I was able to prove the first two inequalities but cannot prove the last one.

The last inequality can be written equivalently as $$|G_1+G_2|^2|G_1+G_3||G_2+G_3|\leq(K_1K_2K_3)^4 |G_1+G_2+2G_3|^2|G_1||G_2|.$$

I have tried many ways to prove it but failed.
I'd be grateful for any help!

**EDIT (Possible counterexample to the initial inequality):** We claim that the inequality $$d(G_1,G_2)\leq d(G_1+G_3, G_2+G_3)+2\log K_1K_2K_3 \Leftrightarrow$$ $$|G_1+G_2|^2|G_1+G_3||G_2+G_3|\leq(K_1K_2K_3)^4 |G_1+G_2+2G_3|^2|G_1||G_2|$$ is wrong.

Let's take a look at the example which you've suggested. We consider the integer lattice $\mathbb{Z}
^2$ and let $G_1$ be an interval $[-N,N]$ on $x$-axis of $\mathbb{Z}^2$, $G_2$ be an interval $[-N,N]$ on $y$-axis of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ and $G_3=[-N,N]\times [-N,N]$ on $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

We see that each of them are approximate groups with $K_1=2$, $K_2=2$ and   $K_3=4$.

Easy to see that $G_1+G_2\equiv G_3=[-N,N]\times [-N,N]$, $G_1+G_3=[-N,N]\times [-2N,2N]$, $G_2+G_3=[-2N,2N]\times [-N,N]$ and $G_1+G_2+2G_3=[-3N,3N]\times[-3N,3N]$. Our inequality becomes $$(2N+1)^6(4N+1)^2\leq 16^4(2N+1)(6N+1)^4$$ and this inequality is obviously wrong because the LHS $\sim N^8$ and the RHS is $\sim N^5$.

Comment: I think there's a typo in the exercise - what is probably meant is to prove that $d(G_1+G_3,G_2+G_3)\leq d(G_1,G_2)+2\log K_1K_2K_3$, which does indeed follow straightforwardly from the first part of the exercise and the previous exercise.

Comment: Indeed, the inequality as written is clearly false - e.g. consider $G_1$ being an interval on the $x$-axis, $G_2$ an interval on the $y$-axis, and $G_3$ a large 2-dimensional box.

Comment: @ThomasBloom, Dear Prof. Bloom! Firstly thank you again for your constant help and I am learning from that. Regarding your first comment: yesterday I intensively tried to prove the last inequality but failed eventually. Later on I recalled that I solved the exercise 2.3.11 while ago which shows that Ruzsa distance in contractive for subgroups, i.e. $d(G+K,H+K)\leq d(G,H)$ for subgroups $G,H,K$ and finite groups are 1-approximate groups. Then I came to conclusion that probably something is wrong with that inequality and when I saw your comment my assumptions were confirmed.

Comment: @ThomasBloom, it seems to me that the last inequality follows directly from Ruzsa triangle inequality: By Ruzsa triangle inequality we have $|G_1+G_2+2G_3||G_1|\leq |2G_1+G_2||G_1+2G_3|\leq K_1K_3|G_1+G_2||G_1+G_3|$ and $|G_1+G_2+2G_3||G_2|\leq |G_1+G_2||2G_2+2G_3|\leq K_2K_3|G_1+G_2||G_2+G_3|$ and multiplying both inequalities we obtain: $|G_1+G_2+2G_3|^2|G_1||G_2|\leq K_1K_2K_3^2|G_1+G_2|^2|G_1+G_3||G_2+G_3|$ and also $K_1K_2K_3^2\leq (K_1K_2K_3)^2$ and we derive our desired inequality.

Comment: @ThomasBloom, regarding you second comment I added an edit to my post. Please take a look.

Comment: I meant a discrete version, with the size of $G_1,G_2$ comparable to $G_3$. So e.g. $G_1=\{(0,n) : 1\leq n\leq N\}$, $G_2=\{(n,0) : 1\leq n\leq N\}$ and $G_3=\{(n,m) : 1\leq n,m\leq N\}$.

Comment: @ThomasBloom, but those sets $G_i$ must contain the origin and must be symmetric, right?

Comment: In that case replace each of those G with the corresponding G union -G union 0.

Comment: @ThomasBloom, that makes sense. I've edited my addendum again. I still cannot find any mistake there. That is weird..

Comment: I don't know why you're using the trivial $K=\lvert G\rvert$ bound for the strength of the additive group. These examples were chosen because they are very structured, so you can take $K_i=O(1)$ for each $G_i$.

Comment: @ThomasBloom, oh gee! Sure! For some reason I forgot about that important moment! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo in the exercise - what it should ask for is the inequality

$$d(G_1+G_3,G_2+G_3)\leq d(G_1,G_2)+2\log K_1K_2K_3.$$

This follows either from the given hint, or from the Ruzsa triangle inequality directly, as you say in the comments.

The inequality the exercise asks for is false, as can be seen e.g. taking $G_1=\{0\}\times P$, $G_2=P\times \{0\}$, and $G_3=P\times P$, where $P=\{-N,\ldots,N\}$ for large $N$.

(The general point is that the inequality as written in the exercise is the opposite of the heuristic that addition of sets generally -increases- the amount of additive structure present.)